# I/O operation on closed file ERROR python

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy tratando de hacer un login, voy en la parte final solo me falta una cosa:

Cuando se registra un usuario lo guarda en un archivo csv, después en la parte del inicio de sesión también guardo lo que introdujo el usuario en un archivo csv, entonces es ahí cuando pongo el `if login.read()==login_main.read():` donde si los 2 contenidos del usuario son iguales entonces ya debería de dejar pasar al usuario.

Pero no es así, me marca un error que dice:

> I/O operation on closed file.

aquí les pongo el codigo completo:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

qtCreatorFile = "main.ui" # Nombre del archivo aquí.

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow,):
    
    
        def __init__(self):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.verifica_datos)
            self.pushButton_regis.clicked.connect(self.registrer)
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
            self.setFixedSize(450, 640)
            
        
            
        def registrer (self):
            cmd = 'registrer.py'
            os.system(cmd)
            
        def verifica_datos(self):
            
            usuario_reg= self.usuario.text()
            passwo_reg = self.passwo.text()
            
            with open("login.csv", 'r') as login:
                print(login.read())
                login.close()
                
            with open("login_main.csv", 'w') as login_main:
                login_main.write(usuario_reg +"\n")
                login_main.write(passwo_reg +"\n")
                
            with open("login_main.csv", 'r') as login_main:
                print(login_main.read())
                login_main.close()
                if login.read()==login_main.read():
                    print("contraseña correcta")
                    cmd = 'index.py'
                    os.system(cmd)
                else:
                    self.pushButton.setParent(None)
                    self.textEdit.setParent(None)
                    cmd = 'contraseña_incorrecta.py'
                    os.system(cmd)
                    os._exit(-1)(qtCreatorFile)
                    print("contraseña es incorrecta!")
                                              
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje de error es claro:

> I/O operation on closed file

**I/O** se llama generalmente a las operaciones de ***Input/Output*** en archivos, en español sería algo como:

> Operación de E/S en un archivo cerrado

Donde **E/S** es **Entrada/Salida** o, en otras palabras, Lectura/Escritura.

Y lo que pasa es que tu mismo has cerrado los archivos. Si sigues la secuencia, encontrarás primero:

```
            with open("login.csv", 'r') as login:
                print(login.read())
                login.close()
```

Y `login.close()` cierra el archivo, por lo que cualquier operación de lectura o escritura posterior a esta línea, generará el error (a menos que se haga otro `open()`).

Algo similar pasa con el archivo `login_main`.

Luego, también sería mejor guardar el contenido de la lectura en una variable para leer una sola vez del disco y realizar el resto de operaciones en memoria, con lo cual ya no hay problema que los archivos estén cerrados.

Poniendo todo junto, quedaría algo como:

```
def verifica_datos(self):
            
            usuario_reg= self.usuario.text()
            passwo_reg = self.passwo.text()
            
            with open("login.csv", 'r') as login:
                login_contenido = login.read()
                print(login_contenido)
                login.close()

            with open("login_main.csv", 'w') as login_main:
                login_main.write(usuario_reg +"\n")
                login_main.write(passwo_reg +"\n")
            
            with open("login_main.csv", 'r') as login_main:
                login_main_contenido = login_main.read()
                print(login_main_contenido)
                login_main.close()
                if login_contenido==login_main_contenido:
                    print("contraseña correcta")
                    cmd = 'index.py'
                    os.system(cmd)
                else:
                    self.pushButton.setParent(None)
                    self.textEdit.setParent(None)
                    cmd = 'contraseña_incorrecta.py'
                    os.system(cmd)
                    os._exit(-1)(qtCreatorFile)
                    print("contraseña es incorrecta!")
```

Comment: Nota adicional, no es necesario cerrar un fichero cuando lo has abierto en un entorno `with`. Precisamente la razón de usar ese entorno es que el fichero se cierra automáticamente cuando el entorno termina.